# how to consume kafka message not from the beginning after a failed spark job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm newbie to kafka and spark, wondering how to recover offset from kafka after a spark job failed.

conditions:

1. say 5gb/s of kafka stream, it's hard to consume from beginning
2. stream data has already been consumed, so how to tell spark to re-consume message / redo the failed task smoothly

I'm not to sure which area to search for, maybe someone can point me to right direction

Answer (score 1):

When we are dealing with kafka, we have must have 2 different topics. One for Success and One for Failed.

Let's say, I have 2 topics Topic-Success and Topic-Failed.
When Kafka processing the data stream successfully, we can mark it and store it in Topic-Success Topic and When Kafka unable to Process data stream, then will store it in Topic-Failed Topic.

So that, when you want to re-consume the failed data stream, we can process that failed one from Topic-Failed Topic. Here you can eliminate re-consuming all the data from-beginning.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In kafka 0.10.x there is a concept of Consumer Group which is used to track the offset of the messages.

If you have made enable.auto.commit=true and auto.offset.reset=latest it will not consume from beginning. Now taking this approach you might also need to track your offsets as the process might failed after consumption. I would suggest you to use this method suggested in Spark Docs to

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

  // some time later, after outputs have completed
  stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
}
```

CanCommitOffsets lies in your hands to commit those messages when your end to end pipeline gets excuted